# My own Autofac container with NServiceBus?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, containers, nservicebus, autofac

I'm trying to get NServiceBus working with the container I already use in my application.

I got excited when I saw that `.AutofacBuilder` will take a preexisting container or scope. However, I also want to register the bus with my container, so that other components in my application can get references to `IBus`.

This leaves me in catch-22. I need a reference to the created bus to register with my container. However, creating the bus requires a reference to the created container.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NServiceBus will register the instance of IBus in the container itself - you don't need to do it.